# Query for date range based on day of the week

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, iif

I'm trying to make a query that presents records from the current day and the day before, but if its a Monday, display the records from the whole weekend as well as the current day.

The logic works, however I can't get date ranges working. I can get singular dates to work.

```
IIf(Weekday(Date())=2,Date()-2,Date())
```

If I try to replace the single dates with ranges like so:

```
IIf(Weekday(Date())=2,Between Date()-2 And Date(),Between Date()-1 And Date())
```

Access tries to append labels from the Table this query is referencing like so. This results in an empty query result.

```
IIf(Weekday(Date())=2,([Table].[Reported Date]) Between Date()-2 And Date(),([Table].[Reported Date]) Between Date()-1 And Date())
```

I'm new to Access, so I don't quite understand what is happening and why it tries to add those labels.

If I'm going about this the wrong way, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for `between` is:

```
<value> between <lower bound> and <upper bound>
```

So this isn't a valid expression:

```
Between Date()-2 And Date()
```

Try something like:

```
YourColumn between Date()-2 and Date()
```

Or alternatively, without `between`:

```
Date()-2 <= YourColumn and YourColumn <= Date()
```

Comment: Access doesn't complain when I do either of those, but I still have an empty query. Should I be writing `[OriginalTable].[Column]` or just `[Column]`?

I should mention that just writing `Column` gets automatically changed to `"Column"`.

Comment: Where are you entering those strings?  In SQL view or in part of the query designer?

Comment: Yeah.. query designer.
I entered it into SQL view instead of design view as a WHERE parameter and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEPART() to grab the day of the week. For example - Monday is considered 2.

The DatePart function uses 1-7 with Sunday being 1.

ex.

Declare your variable and use the DATEPART(w,GETDATE()).

Once you have this you can use your conditionals:

```
if (@todayDate_PT = 2)
     'query'
else
     'query'
```